# Were ISIS soldiers ordered to rape women 'to make them Muslim'?

Tags: sexual-abuse, isis

[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/10/08/middleeast/isis-rape-theology-soldiers-rape-women-to-make-them-muslim/index.html):

> Headline: ISIS soldiers told to rape women 'to make them Muslim'
>
> The 22-year-old says the militant who picked her out raped her -- but
> not before trying to justify himself.
>
> "He showed me a letter and said, 'This shows any captured women will
> become Muslim if 10 ISIS fighters rape her.' There was a flag of ISIS
> and a picture of Abu Bakr Al Baghdadi."
>
> After abusing her, he passed her on to 11 of his friends, who also
> raped her.
>
> "ISIS fighters told us, 'This is the rule of Abu Bakr al-Baghdadi and we must do it,'" Noor explains.

The above report implies that ISIS authority sanctioned the gang rape of women 'to make them Muslim'. Does any convincing evidence of such thing exist? Or, is the report entirely based on the claims of an anonymous Yazidi woman?

Comment: The title asks about rape as a method of converting, but the body asks about sanctioned gang rape. Are you skeptical of whether rape is sanctioned by the ISIS leadership, or whether ISIS tells its fighters that rape victims are converted to Islam by the rape?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed point addressed.

Comment: You'll likely not find anything definitive, besides anecdotal accounts of victims providing testimony.

Comment: Yeah........that makes no sense.  How can anyone convert to anything other than by a conscious voluntary act of free will?    If that line is correct, it is likely a sign of pure barbarism, and lack of any sound mind.

Comment: But also, even if this cannot be substantiated by sources outside of the group accused, is there a need to discount the claim the woman made?